# RoyalSlider change background from a div with each slide

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I use RoyalSlider for my website and i want to change my background color to a different color with each slider.

The div that i want to change is *#slide6* like this:

```
$('#slide6').css({"background-color":"red"});
```

but i don't know how to do it. Here is the HTML structure

```
<div id="content-slider-1" class="royalSlider contentSlider rsDefault">
    <div> 
    <h3>Slide HTML Text</h3>
    <p>This is dummy copy.</p>
    <span class="rsTmb">HTML text</span>
    </div>
```

Maybe i can use something like data-color='red'and then with an if/else to the background color?

I can see the data from each slide with:

```
var slider = $('#content-slider-1').data('royalSlider');
    slider.ev.on('rsBeforeAnimStart', function() { 
        console.log( $('#content-slider-1').data('royalSlider').currSlide ); 
});
```

Can somebody help me out with this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class on the div wrapping each slide, and control the background color from your CSS

```
<div id="content-slider-1" class="royalSlider contentSlider rsDefault">
<div class="slide1"> 
<h3>Slide HTML Text</h3>
<p>This is dummy copy.</p>
<span class="rsTmb">HTML text</span>
</div>
<div class="slide2"> 
<h3>Slide HTML Text</h3>
<p>This is dummy copy.</p>
<span class="rsTmb">HTML text</span>
</div>

.slide1 {background-color: red}
.slide2 {background-color: blue}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to change the background color of #slide6. This is the div where <div id="content-slider-1"</div> is in.